# Why does Sheldon not stop Leonard from sitting in his spot on the couch?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

From first episode of first season of **The Big Bang Theory**, it is shown that Sheldon has an attachment to his spot on couch and does not let anybody sit on it. However, in **Bat Jar Conjecture**, we can see Leonard sitting in his spot and he was on chair. How come he does not stop Leonard from sitting in his spot?

[image]

There is another instance. In first episode of season two, Raj was sitting in his spot.

In **the Earworm Reverberation**, he says that he is very protective of this while making a video. We have clearly seen him show utter intolerance when anybody tries to sit there. So, why does Sheldon not stop Leonard from sitting in his spot on the couch?

Comment: Notice that they're practicing for the Physics Bowl where Sheldon is indeed seated on the far *right* (his right), though, so maybe it's more important for him to replicate *that* in this scenario. (I don't know about the other episode, though. Maybe Sheldon's more lenient when *he's* not using the couch.)

Comment: @Walt - There are a bunch of times when Sheldon ignores people sitting in his spot. I'm guessing it's either a directing goof (likely) or that Sheldon has some rules/regulations guiding who can sit in his spot and when that we simply aren't privy to (also quite likely).

Comment: Sheldon also allows Leonard to sit in his spot at the end of the Bat Jar Conjecture during Penny's trivial pursuit 'pop culture' competition....that doesn't seem to go with Sheldon's personality at all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the episode: **Bat Jar Conjecture**, Sheldon is indeed trying to replicate his desired sitting arrangement of his team at the upcoming Physics Bowl.

It is to be noticed that, he tries to assert himself as the team lead and Sheldon is known for practising/enacting things exactly, especially before important events like the Physics Bowl here, themed costume parties(remember that he even wears a linen underwear for a renaissance themed costume party).

[When you're bossing around, you generally try to stand tall or sit on a higher pedestal with a straight back, and Sheldon does exactly that. (Appreciate the direction)]

Comment: It's one of his quirks and I agree that he has tendency to be a boss or team leader.  gud explanation